# Disable WordPress popup box exit behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have a WordPress website where i am using a popup box that should be exit only by filling the form instead of clicking by "X" button or "esc" or mouse click outside the popup.
Website is: http://www.savvyparentingsupport.com/babytips/dwnldtips-2/